# Entity Framework generic model design required as an alternative to numerous lookup tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lookup-tables

I am starting on a new ASP.NET MVC project, using Entity Framework 5 CodeFirst. The application to be developed was originally going to use a number of different lookup tables, some for simple attributes that can be assigned to a product (in this case, a gun)

E.g.

- Item Condition (Poor, Average, Good, Excellent etc.)
- Gun Orientation (left-handed, right-handed, ambidextrous etc.)

There are about 10+ of these 'categorisation/attribute' tables.

In addition there is the need for 'Make' and 'Model' also. These 2 are related (in that a Make can have many different Models).

Finally, a few of the categorisation tables need to relate to one another. For example, some 'Makes' only produce certain types of gun ('GunTypes' lookup table), and some Gun Mechanisms ('GunMechanisms' lookup table) are only relevant to certain Gun Types.

Initially I had designed my application with a Model class for each of these entities, implementing the necessary relationships to handle the above requirements. However, because some elements will need to be re-used for non-gun versions of this application, I've been asked to get rid of each of these elements/classes/tables and instead, use a more generic approach along the lines of having a 'Category' and 'Term' entity.

For example, I initially went with something like below...

```
public class Category
{
    // A Category would be, for example, 'Gun Condition', 'Gun Orientation', 'Make' etc.
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}

    // A Category will have any number of Terms associated with it.
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
}

public class Term
{
    // A Term would be, for example, 'Excellent Condition', 'Good Condition', 'Left-Handed', 'Right-Handed' etc.
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}

    // A Term belongs to a Category.
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Gun
{
    // Edited for brevity.
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Descrip { get; set;}

    // All of the terms (what were originally properties), e.g. 1 Term in the collection would be 'Excellent Condition' with the Category 'Gun Condition'. A 2nd Term might be 'Left-Handed' with the Category 'Gun Orientation', and so on. 
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set;}
}
```

However, as mentioned above, I need to be able to deal with:

a) items like 'Make' & 'Model', where they related to one another;

b) the 'many-to-many' style scenario, where a 'Make' only produce certain 'GunType's, and a 'GunType' will be relevant to certain 'GunMechanism's (e.g. an air rifle (Gun Type) would have both a 'Break Barrel' & 'Pre-charged' Gun Mechanism).

I am really struggling with the implementation of this model design, which has been put forward as a firm requirement.

Comment: First off: Why would `Gun` have a `ICollection<Term>`? Isn't it better to use a `Category` since it already contains a `ICollection<Term>`

Comment: My thinking was that the term is the actual property value essentially. So by assigning a Term to a Gun, you have both the Category (via the relationship in the Term object) and the Term/Value. If I have 'Category' against my Gun, it will contain all of the 'possible' values for that category, but not the 'set' value for that gun.